# Why aren't my CPUs numbered sequentially?

Tags: arch-linux, cpu

I'm using Arch Linux

```
Linux JamesPC 4.10.11-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Apr 18 08:39:42 CEST 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

While trying to figure out why my system monitor is suddenly only showing one CPU (when I should have six):
[image]

I found this oddity that I think may be causing the system monitor to not work properly:

cat /proc/cpuinfo:

```
[gilmoreja@JamesPC ~]$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 21
model       : 1
model name  : AMD FX(tm)-6100 Six-Core Processor
stepping    : 2
microcode   : 0x600063d
cpu MHz     : 3311.103
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 6
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 3
apicid      : 16
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt lwp fma4 nodeid_msr topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb cpb hw_pstate vmmcall arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold
bugs        : fxsave_leak sysret_ss_attrs null_seg
bogomips    : 6624.13
TLB size    : 1536 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm 100mhzsteps hwpstate cpb

processor   : 3
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 21
model       : 1
model name  : AMD FX(tm)-6100 Six-Core Processor
stepping    : 2
microcode   : 0x600063d
cpu MHz     : 3311.103
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 6
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 3
apicid      : 17
initial apicid  : 1
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt lwp fma4 nodeid_msr topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb cpb hw_pstate vmmcall arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold
bugs        : fxsave_leak sysret_ss_attrs null_seg
bogomips    : 6623.14
TLB size    : 1536 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm 100mhzsteps hwpstate cpb

processor   : 4
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 21
model       : 1
model name  : AMD FX(tm)-6100 Six-Core Processor
stepping    : 2
microcode   : 0x600063d
cpu MHz     : 3311.103
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 6
core id     : 2
cpu cores   : 3
apicid      : 18
initial apicid  : 2
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt lwp fma4 nodeid_msr topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb cpb hw_pstate vmmcall arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold
bugs        : fxsave_leak sysret_ss_attrs null_seg
bogomips    : 6623.22
TLB size    : 1536 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm 100mhzsteps hwpstate cpb

processor   : 5
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 21
model       : 1
model name  : AMD FX(tm)-6100 Six-Core Processor
stepping    : 2
microcode   : 0x600063d
cpu MHz     : 3311.103
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 6
core id     : 3
cpu cores   : 3
apicid      : 19
initial apicid  : 3
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt lwp fma4 nodeid_msr topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb cpb hw_pstate vmmcall arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold
bugs        : fxsave_leak sysret_ss_attrs null_seg
bogomips    : 6623.22
TLB size    : 1536 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm 100mhzsteps hwpstate cpb

processor   : 6
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 21
model       : 1
model name  : AMD FX(tm)-6100 Six-Core Processor
stepping    : 2
microcode   : 0x600063d
cpu MHz     : 3311.103
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 6
core id     : 4
cpu cores   : 3
apicid      : 20
initial apicid  : 4
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt lwp fma4 nodeid_msr topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb cpb hw_pstate vmmcall arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold
bugs        : fxsave_leak sysret_ss_attrs null_seg
bogomips    : 6623.23
TLB size    : 1536 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm 100mhzsteps hwpstate cpb

processor   : 7
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 21
model       : 1
model name  : AMD FX(tm)-6100 Six-Core Processor
stepping    : 2
microcode   : 0x600063d
cpu MHz     : 3311.103
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 6
core id     : 5
cpu cores   : 3
apicid      : 21
initial apicid  : 5
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt lwp fma4 nodeid_msr topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb cpb hw_pstate vmmcall arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold
bugs        : fxsave_leak sysret_ss_attrs null_seg
bogomips    : 6623.22
TLB size    : 1536 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm 100mhzsteps hwpstate cpb
```

lscpu:

```
[gilmoreja@JamesPC ~]$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                6
On-line CPU(s) list:   0,3-7
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    3
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             AuthenticAMD
CPU family:            21
Model:                 1
Model name:            AMD FX(tm)-6100 Six-Core Processor
Stepping:              2
CPU MHz:               3311.103
BogoMIPS:              6624.13
Virtualization:        AMD-V
L1d cache:             16K
L1i cache:             64K
L2 cache:              2048K
L3 cache:              8192K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0,3-7
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt lwp fma4 nodeid_msr topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb cpb hw_pstate vmmcall arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold
```

My CPUs are not listed sequentially, and instead they're numbered 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, and 7.

Why aren't my CPUs numbered sequentially? How can I fix it so they are?

Comment: _Note that [...] CPU logical numbers follow the kernel where there is no guarantee of sequential numbering._ (source: `lscpu` manual page)

Comment: That's interesting. So there's no way to influence the outcome at all? Why would the kernel skip available numbers?

Comment: I'm not a kernel guy but [maybe this helps...](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/281153)

Answer (score 1):

The Linux kernel assigns a CPU number for each CPU listed in the machine's APIC table (see [commands for dumping CPU table](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/280766/how-does-the-kernel-assign-cpu-ids-to-physical-cores/281153#281153)). The table contains an "enabled" bit for each core. The FX-6100 is actually manufactured as an 8-core processor but 2 cores are disabled by AMD - [Tomshardware says](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/fx-8150-zambezi-bulldozer-990fx,3043-2.html) *"All seven of the Zambezi-based FX processors employ the same silicon. Some of the processors have one Bulldozer module disabled, and some have two turned off."* This is probably done when one core fails QA - the 8 core processor can have some cores disabled and still be sold as a lower spec part.

Two cores being disabled would match your description that cores "0, 3, 4, 5, 6, and 7" are functional - cores 1 and 2 would be present but disabled in the APIC table. I don't have an FX-6100 to dump the table and check this for sure, but it seems a likely explanation.